# How to Handle a Trend-Stationary Dep. Variable and Stationary and Non-Stationary (Unit-Root) Ind. Variables?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity, unit-root

I am trying to determine the best way to proceed when one has a mix of stationary, trend-stationary and non-stationary variables with unit roots.

My dependent variable $Y_t$ is a trend-stationary variable. My independent variables $X_t^1$, $X_t^2$ etc. are a mix of stationary $I(0)$, trend-stationary (stationary after extracting a deterministic time trend from the data), and non-stationary $I(1)$ processes containing unit roots.

One thing I can do is to make all variables stationary using the appropriate transformation (i.e. remove the deterministic trend for the trend-stationary variables and take the first difference of the $I(1)$ variables). Taking that into account, I have two questions:

1. Assuming I were to make the transformations described above, can I use these transformed series in an OLS (with Newey-West SEs), and would that somehow create problems or introduce bias in the estimation? If yes, what is the best way to handle this issue?
2. Can I use an ARDL model? Another thing that I have read I could possibly do is to use an ARDL model since it can handle both $I(0)$ and $I(1)$ variables. I am not quite familiar with this modeling framework and I am unsure if I need any cointegrating relationships among my variables for this model to work or if there are any other conditions necessary to use this model. I am also not sure how this model deals with trend-stationary variables.

Beyond my questions, any suggestions on how best to deal with this issue would be greatly appreciated!